# How would I write the following applescript in Obj-C AppScript? ASTranslate was of no help =(

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-processing, sourceforge-appscript

The translation tool isn't able to translate this working code.  I copied  it out of a working script.

```
set pathToTemp to (POSIX path of ((path to desktop) as string))

-- change jpg to pict
tell application "Image Events"
    try
        launch
            set albumArt to open file (pathToTemp & "albumart.jpg")
            save albumArt as PICT in file (pathToTemp & "albumart.pict")
            --the first 512 bytes are the PICT header, so it reads from byte 513
            --this is to allow the image to be added to an iTunes track later.
            set albumArt to (read file (pathToTemp & "albumart.pict") from 513 as picture)
        close
    end try
end tell
```

The code is taking a jpg image, converting it to a PICT file, and then reading the file minus the header (the first 512 bytes).  Later in the script, `albumArt` will be added to an iTunes track.

I tried translating the code (minus the comments), but ASTranslate froze for a good 2 minutes before giving me this:

```
Untranslated event 'earsffdr'

#import "IEGlue/IEGlue.h"
IEApplication *imageEvents = [IEApplication applicationWithName: @"Image Events"];
IELaunchCommand *cmd = [[imageEvents launch] ignoreReply];
id result = [cmd send];

#import "IEGlue/IEGlue.h"
IEApplication *imageEvents = [IEApplication applicationWithName: @"Image Events"];
IEReference *ref = [[imageEvents files] byName: @"/Users/Doom/Desktop/albumart.jpg"];
id result = [[ref open] send];

#import "IEGlue/IEGlue.h"
IEApplication *imageEvents = [IEApplication applicationWithName: @"Image Events"];
IEReference *ref = [[imageEvents images] byName: @"albumart.jpg"];
IESaveCommand *cmd = [[[ref save] in: [[imageEvents files] byName: @"/Users/Doom/Desktop/albumart.pict"]] as: [IEConstant PICT]];
id result = [cmd send];

'crdwrread'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "objcrenderer.pyc", line 283, in renderCommand
KeyError: 'crdwrread'


'cascrgdut'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "objcrenderer.pyc", line 283, in renderCommand
KeyError: 'cascrgdut'


'crdwrread'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "objcrenderer.pyc", line 283, in renderCommand
KeyError: 'crdwrread'


Untranslated event 'rdwrread'

OK
```

I have no clue how to make sense of this.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` is a Standard Additions command; ASTranslate doesn't support scripting additions, only scriptable applications, so you will have to translate it yourself.

Use ASDictionary to export the Standard Additions dictionary to HTML and create an objc-appscript glue (SAGlue). You can then use -[SAApplication init] to create a new SAApplication instance and send your `read` command to that.

Alternatively, you could skip Standard Additions completely and use NSData to read and slice the file and build the NSAppleEventDescriptor yourself.